# Last record then remove text from SQL statement and replace with blank or another character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL select statement from SQL server that puts text together from a dynamic table and creates a union statement.  I then copy this statement into Oracle SQL Developer to hit an Oracle database to get counts or min/max columns, or whatever.  My query is similar to this:

```
'Select ' + a.column1 + 'from' + a.tablename + 'where ' + a.column1 + '= 123' + 'UNION ALL' 
from Mytable a where a.tablename = 'MYTABLENAMEHERE'
```

So I then get a list of 20 tables then cut/paste this into Oracle for results.

My question is (and this may be a dumb question I just wanted to know how to do it in SQL) is that the output on the last record has the 'UNION ALL' at the end of it without a ";" that Oracle needs so I always have to remove it on the last record.

How do I tell SQL when it's the last record to replace the 'UNION ALL' and replace with a ";" terminator statement so that when I cut and paste it, I don't have to remove it each time?

Just curious from the experts!

Comment: Take a look at the STUFF function.

Comment: why is this question tagged sql-server if you are using oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with a case sentence if the current record is the last one and, in that case, not print the UNION ALL:

```
select 'Select ' + a.column1 + 'from' + a.tablename + 'where ' + a.column1 + '= 123'
+ case when (select count(*) from Mytable where tablename=a.tablename)=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by a.tablename desc) then ';' else ' UNION ALL' end 
from Mytable a where a.tablename = 'MYTABLENAMEHERE'
```

Comment: Hi JC.  Thanks for that.  I think we're close.  I'm getting an invalid object name "a" after the "Select count(*) from a".  I tried to replace that with my permanent table name and the syntax is right but it's not taking the last UNION ALL off on the last record...

Comment: Yes, that "a" should be your table name. Try changing the order on the OVER:  OVER(order by a.column1)

Comment: I tested just the statement in a SELECT statement.  "select
case when (select count(*) from mytable)=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by a.tablename) then ';' else 'UNION ALL' end
from mytable a" - This seems to work with the last row putting a ';' at the end.  In the above code, I can't put an additional SELECT in front of the CASE without error. - Also alias of "a" still doesn't work there.

Comment: I got it: we're missing the "where" in the "count" sub select. Replace it with: select count(*) from mytable where tablename =a.tablename

Comment: Hey JC. I did that in the WHERE statement and the Syntax is okay; however it's not taking off the UNION ALL on the last record...

Comment: I just looked it again...it's putting the character of ";" on the first row and UNION ALL on the other rows..it's doing the first record instead of the last...almost there!

Comment: Just use the same order: sort your full sentence adding a sort by a.column1 at the end or, sort the over with a desc: OVER(order by a.column desc)

Comment: I just added a desc to the OVER(order by a.column desc) and that worked.  Thank you so much!